# Qt QProgressBar indeterminate

Tags: c++, qt

My application needs to do some operations which might take a second but might also take 10 minutes. For this purpose I need to show a QProgressDialog with indeterminate QProgressBar during the operation.

```
QProgressDialog dlg( this );
dlg.setBar( new QProgressBar() );
dlg->setMaximum( 0 );
dlg->setMinimum( 0 );
dlg.setModal( true );
dlg.show();

//operation ...

dlg.close();
```

During my operation the dialog shows up, **is transparent, has no progressbar** and after the operation it closes.

Does anyone know what I can do to show a modal dialog which prevents the user from interacting with the application and which shows the user an indeterminate progressbar?

Comment: Why are your `maximum` and `minimum` both `0`?

Comment: @Cyber Well I tried it with and without min/max values. I read somewhere on the Internet that I should set both to 0 to show an indeterminate progressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one thing that you might need is that you call `QApplication::processEvents()` while looping over your entries. 
Quoting from `QCoreApplication` docs:

> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation (e.g. copying a file).

and I think in this particular case the application will not update the appearance of your `QProgressDialog` while it is busy performing the long operation unless you call `QApplication::processEvents()`.

If you have fixed range and you call `setValue()` as your loop progresses (quoting from the `QProgressDialog` docs):

> If the progress dialog is modal (see QProgressDialog::QProgressDialog()), setValue() calls QApplication::processEvents()

(I am omitting here the warning which cautions that this can cause issues with re-entrancy).`

Note that when I tried your code it created a dialog like what you would expect if you only remove the line

`dlg.setBar( new QProgressBar() );`

As was said in another answer, `QProgressDialog` has its own `QProgressBar` so unless you have special requirements, this should do what you need.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you don't create your own `QProgressBar`. The `QProgressDialog` has its own bar inside, and propagates all the methods from dialog to bar. What's more, to make your window modal use `exec` not `show`, or `setModal(true)` first. To close it, connect some signal (of a finished work) to the `cancel()` slot (or user will have to click *Cancel* button).

```
QProgressDialog dialog;
dialog.setRange(0,0);
dialog.exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of the `QProgressDialog`s method `setBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#setBar) states, that "... the progress dialog takes ownership of the progress bar ...", however I found a [forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10433-setBar-%28-QProgressBar-*-bar-%29?s=470a8e5190f3909e768e0002929b97c8) about the exact same problem you have.

In that post the last answer of the user ShaChris23 states, that this problem can be solved by passing the pointer to your `QProgressDialog` in the constructor of the `QProgressBar`, to set it as parent:

```
dlg.setBar( new QProgressBar(&dlg) );
```